# Getting Every Possible Combination Of Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I were to have a recordset that just returned:

`SELECT * FROM USERS`

```
    Name | Gender |   Company
    Bob  |  male  |  Abc Inc.
    Bob  |  male  |  Xyz Inc.
    Bob  |  male  |    NULL
```

And I would like it to return this:

```
    Name | Gender |   Company
    NULL |  NULL  |    NULL
    NULL |  NULL  |    Abc Inc.
    NULL |  male  |    NULL
    NULL |  male  |    Abc Inc.
    NULL |  NULL  |    Xyz Inc.
    NULL |  male  |    Xyz Inc.
    Bob  |  NULL  |    NULL
    Bob  |  NULL  |    Abc Inc.
    Bob  |  male  |    NULL
    Bob  |  male  |    Abc Inc.
    Bob  |  NULL  |    Xyz Inc.
    Bob  |  male  |    Xyz Inc.
```

How is it accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Name, Gender, Company
from T
group by Name, Gender, Company with cube
```

Comment: You missed a `distinct` there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, GENDER, COMPANY FROM TABLE
GROUP BY NAME, GENDER, COMPANY WITH CUBE
```